# Efficient Management and ID Handling of Instagram Posts from Multiple Accounts

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, instagram

[image: a sample post from instagram]

*I'm currently developing an Social media application that is similar to Instagram posts from multiple accounts, and I'm curious about how Instagram manages and handles the posts' identification in such a large-scale environment. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide me with insights on the following aspects:*

**Post Identification:**

1. How does Instagram assign unique identifiers (IDs) to posts? Are these IDs globally unique or specific to each user's account?
2. Are there any patterns or conventions followed in generating these IDs?
3. Is there a possibility of collisions or overlaps in the ID space, and if so, how does Instagram mitigate this?

**Account Segregation:**

1. How does Instagram ensure that posts from different accounts are segregated and associated with the correct user account?
2. Are there any specific data structures or databases employed to efficiently store and retrieve posts for each account?
3. How does Instagram handle the scenario when multiple users upload posts simultaneously?

**Scalability and Performance:**

1. With millions of users and a massive number of posts, how does Instagram manage the scalability and performance of handling and processing posts?
2. Are there any optimization techniques or strategies employed to ensure fast retrieval and efficient management of posts across the platform?

**I'm particularly interested in understanding the underlying architecture and techniques employed by Instagram to handle the management and identification of posts across their platform. Any insights, technical explanations, or references to relevant documentation would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!**